# Is the Writer Monad Now Suitable for Large Lazy Lists?

Tags: haskell

I've read in multiple places that the writer monad of a list keeps that full list in memory, and therefore shouldn't be used in anything other than small samples (no logging, for instance).

[For instance, read here](https://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-01-21-writer-monad.html)

However, to test the claim, I wrote the following program, and actually showed that it successfully outputs an infinite list lazily!

```
import Control.Monad.Writer

createInfiniteList :: Int -> Writer [Int] ()
createInfiniteList i = do
  tell [i]
  createInfiniteList (i+1)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let x = execWriter $ createInfiniteList 1
  print x
```

I've watched this program output over 1 billion items (it runs very fast), and monitored that the memory usage never went past 0.1% on my machine.

Has the writer monad been rewritten to fix the original problem?  Can I count on it continuing to work this way in the future?

note- I am aware that better logging monads exist (I use those elsewhere)...  My desired use case is not logging (but it is similar)

Comment: @n.m. From Hackage, `while >>= combines the outputs of the subcomputations using mappend.`....  So the final value created is one giant infinite list.  You can directly see it in the `print` output, which is always in the form of an unfinished list `[1,2,3....`, which no closing bracket.

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't woke up yet. Please disregard.

Comment: Obviously applications of mappend cannot be left-nested as claimed in the linked article.

Comment: IIUC, the real reason `WriterT` is considered bad (compared to `StateT`) is that you end up with a `mappend` on *every* bind, not just ones that produce writer output. In contrast, a `StateT` computation that never touches the state just threads the value along untouched. The constant uses of `mappend` on `mempty` end up being unnecessarily expensive in real programs, since `tell` is used infrequently relative to other monadic actions in a transformer stack, but it wouldn’t matter in a toy program like this, since every action is a `tell`.

Answer (score 3):

There are two factors at play here. The way the `<>`/`mappend` calls are nested, and whether the entire log is kept in memory.

#### How are the `<>` calls nested?

This depends on how you write your code *using* Writer, not on Writer's implementation. To see why, lets cheat.

```
data Tree a = Nil | Leaf a | Node (Tree a) (Tree a)
  deriving (Show)

instance Semigroup (Tree a)
  where x <> y = Node x y

instance Monoid (Tree a)
  where mempty = Nil
```

This is not a proper monoid, since `<>` is not associative. `x <> (y <> z)` gives `Node x (Node y z)` whereas `(x <> y) <> z)` gives `Node (Node x y) z`. It allows us to tell after the fact whether the Writer's "log" was reduced left-nested or right nested.

```
go :: Int -> Writer (Tree Int) ()
go i
  | i < 5
    = do tell (Leaf i)
         go (i+1)
  | otherwise
    = pure ()

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let (result, log) = runWriter $ go 1
  putStrLn (render log)

render Nil = "Nil"
render (Leaf x) = show x
render (Node x y) = "(" ++ render x ++ ") <> (" ++ render y ++ ")"
```

With this, you get: `(1) <> ((2) <> ((3) <> ((4) <> (Nil))))`

Clearly right-nested. Hence how you could generate an infinite list as the "log" of a `Writer` and consume it as it was generated in a relatively small amount of space.

But swap the order of the `tell` and the recursion, so that it looks like this:

```
go :: Int -> Writer (Tree Int) ()
go i
  | i < 5
    = do go (i+1)
         tell (Leaf i)
  | otherwise
    = pure ()
```

And you get this: `((((Nil) <> (4)) <> (3)) <> (2)) <> (1)`. Now it's left-nested, infinite recursion does not work:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer

createInfiniteList :: Int -> Writer [Int] ()
createInfiniteList i = do
  createInfiniteList (i+1)
  tell [i]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let x = execWriter $ createInfiniteList 1
  print x
```

This never prints anything, and consumes an ever-growing amount of memory.

Basically the structure of the `<>` calls is similar to the structure of your `Writer` expressions. Everywhere you bind in a call to another function (including the equivalent in a do-block), all of the `<>` calls resulting from that call will be "inside parentheses". So `tell _ >> recurse` results in right-nested `<>`s, while `recurse >> tell _` results in left-nested `<>`s, and more complex call-graphs result in similarly-structured nesting of `<>`s.

#### Forcing the result builds the entire log

Another particular thing about your test program is that it doesn't use the "result" of the Writer at all, only the "log". Obviously if the recursion is infinite there's never any final result at all, but if we change your program like so:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer

createLargeList :: Int -> Writer [Int] ()
createLargeList i
  | i < 50000000
    = do tell [i]
         createLargeList (i+1)
  | otherwise
    = pure ()

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let (result, log) = runWriter $ createLargeList 1
  print $ length log
  print result
```

Then it behaves similarly; `length` consumes the list as it is produced and completes in short order (and relatively low memory usage). After that the `()` is readily available and is printed immediately.

But if we change it to print the result first:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer

createLargeList :: Int -> Writer [Int] ()
createLargeList i
  | i < 50000000
    = do tell [i]
         createLargeList (i+1)
  | otherwise
    = pure ()

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let (result, log) = runWriter $ createLargeList 1
  print result
  print $ length log
```

Then on my system this takes much longer, and consumes nearly 15 GB of RAM<sup>1</sup>. It does have to materialise the log fully in RAM just to get at the final result, even when the `<>`s are right-nested and the log can be consumed lazily.

Technically I believe it is not building the *list* in memory, but rather a chain of thunks applying `<>` to singleton lists, which is just as long as the final list and probably uses more memory per link in the chain. The resulting list is still consumed by `length` as it is generated by forcing those thunks, but that doesn't really help since the entire thunk chain had to be generated to get at the final `()` result, instead of having the thunk chain itself generates as `length` demands more of the list.

---

<sup>1</sup> That's compiling like `ghc foo.hs`; if I compile with `-O2` then it behaves similarly to printing the length of the log first. This is a fairly simple case for GHC to inline everything and figure out a better way of computing the same result; I wouldn't assume its optimisations could address this problem if the program were more complicated.

Comment: As for solutions, using a [`dlist`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dlist) as the underlying monoid solves the first problem (nesting). I don't think it solves the second (keeping the log in memory)––I don't know of any good solution to the second... curious about it

Comment: @Ben Interesting, but I think this is more generic pitfalls of laziness than specific to `Writer`.  Both problems are variants of "you can't wait on a whole infinite list".  The first failure waits for a whole list to be created before it starts outputting any of the "logging" messages.  The second blocks the ready-to-use messages in memory, not printing anything until the length of an infinite list is printed.  I could write a non `Writer`-non `append` program that has the same problems.

Comment: @jamshidh Essentially yes. But "generic pitfalls with laziness" is all the problems with Writer for large lists ever were. Your test program works well because it happens to avoid these issues, not because Writer has been rewritten to be more large-lazy-list-friendly. In particular, never using the result seems quite unrealistic for real uses of Writer; you could just use Monoid directly if the log is all you need.